# Converting Date with PHP

Tags: php, date

I have a difficulties regarding converting date into different format

The initial date format is 09/17/2014 which is, mm/dd/YYYY

I want to convert this into a new variable that shows Wednesday, September 17, 2014

How do i implement this?

thanks a bunch

Comment: see this http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: check [The DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Answer (score 3):

Try with the following code using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$dt = new DateTime('09/17/2014');
echo $dt->format('l, F d, Y');
```

Or use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
echo date('l, F d, Y', strtotime("09/17/2014"));
```

Comment: Better to use DateTime::createFromFormat and don't forget about TimeZone

Answer (score 0):

Use strtotime.

```
echo date('l, F d, Y', strtotime("09/17/2014"));
```

Refer
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php